# Como transformar as linha de uma consulta em colunas e agrupar de acordo com os 4 primeiros caracteres?

Tags: php, mysql, matriz

Gostaria de transformar o retorno da minha consulta SQL em um matriz onde eu seleciono os quatro primeiros caracteres, que funcionarão como uma espécie de grupo, e retornar os valores referentes a quele grupo em colunas. Estou analisando a linguagem PHP.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como eu gostaria**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Na clásula `GROUP BY` use a função [`left()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left) que retorna os N caracteres a esquerda da string, como critério de agrupamento.

```
SELECT * FROM tabela GROUP BY LEFT(PRODUCT, 4)
```

[Exemplo funcional - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/56627/1)

```
create table t (
   id int(11) primary key auto_increment,
   product varchar(50),
   value int(11)
);

insert into t values
(null, 'A00102', 50),
(null, 'A00103', 20),
(null, 'A00104', 60),
(null, 'B00101', 80),
(null, 'B00102', 10),
(null, 'C00101', 22);
```

Consulta:

```
SELECT left(product, 4) as grupo, sum(`value`) as total FROM t GROUP BY left(product, 4)
```

Retorno:

```
grupo|total
A001 |130
B001 |90
C001 |22
```